# Baking matzah on tin foil

Tags: passover, matzah

The poskim bring down (in [OH 461](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.461?lang=bi)) that there are people who bake matzah on a piece of paper. [They all seem to say](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.461.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that you should *not* do it, but if you did the paper won't stop the heat from getting to the matzah, and it's kosher.
I wonder why they say you shouldn't do it. Is it because paper in their days was kinda thick and bulky, and really does stop the heat for a while till it burns up, just not long enough to forbid the matzah? Or is any kind of barrier between the matzah and the cooking surface forbidden lechatchilah?
If the reason is the former, I wonder about thin tin foil. It conducts heat much better than paper; I assume it would become the same temperature as the matzah oven instantly. Theoretically it slows things down, but only for an instant.
If that is permitted lechatchilah, would it be a good idea? Instead of draping the matzah on a stick, and you need to be skilled to get it to lie smoothly in the oven with no folds - and you don't get a second chance - you'd arrange it on the tin foil, punch holes in it, and then move the whole tin foil into the oven like a pizza. Maybe it would make the process easier?
Are there health issues with the aluminum in a matzah oven?

Comment: Foil only conducts heat if it's flush with the hot surface. If it's wrinkled at all it could trap an air bubble which is a very poor conductor. (I don't know how realistic this concern is in any given cooking set up.)